# Using objective-c in linux

Tags: objective-c

I try to use objective-c in linux.
Which version of iOS is "supported" when using compilers like gobjc++, gobjc, libgnustep-base-dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None.  I don't know of any non-Apple tool chain that can be used to compile Objective-C for iOS devices.  For a start, you at least need an ARM cross compiler.

Comment: As far as I know, llvm works fine on Linux. But... compilation of code is probably the easiest problem to solve for this.